# Capture a Screen Shot of UIView - Slow Performance

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, thumbnails

I have a Drawing App of sorts, I would like to create a Snapshot of the Canvas UIView (both on and off screen) and then scale it down. The code I have for doing that take bloody for ever on an iPad 3. Simulator there is no delay.  The Canvas is 2048x2048.

Is there another way I should be doing this? Or something I have a miss in the code?

Thank you!

```
-(UIImage *) createScreenShotThumbnailWithWidth:(CGFloat)width{
        // Size of our View
    CGSize size = editorContentView.bounds.size;


        //First Grab our Screen Shot at Full Resolution
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [editorContentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        //Calculate the scal ratio of the image with the width supplied.
    CGFloat ratio = 0;
    if (size.width > size.height) {
        ratio = width / size.width;
    } else {
         ratio = width / size.height;
    }

        //Setup our rect to draw the Screen shot into 
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(ratio * size.width, ratio * size.height);

        //Send back our screen shot
    return [self imageWithImage:screenShot scaledToSize:newSize];

}
```

Comment: It's important to remember that the simulator is just that, a simulator, and not a true representation of performance of an iPad, iPhone or iPod. Any code there has access to the full resources of your computer, which will be considerably more powerful than the iPad 3. As AliSoftware mentions below, it might be a better idea to scale your image before trying to draw it, that way you cut out about 50% of the work you're currently doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the **"Time Profiler" Instrument** ("Product" Menu -> "Profile") to check where in your code you spend the most of your time? (use it with your Device of course, not the Simulator, to have realistic profiling). I'd guess it is not in the image capture portion you quoted in your question, but in your rescaling method `imageWithImage:scaledToSize:` method.

Instead of rendering the image at its whole size in a context, then rescaling the image to the final size, **you should render the layer in the context directly at the expected size by applying some affine transform to the context**.

So simply use **`CGContextConcatCTM(someScalingAffineTransform);`** on `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` right after your line `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);`, to apply an scaling affine transform that will make the layer be rendered at a different scale/size.

*This way it will be directly rendered as the expected size which will be much faster, instead of being rendered at 100% and then having you to rescale it afterwards in a time-consuming way*

Comment: Thank you for your Suggestion. It was a great lead to my current solution. Using `CGContextConcatCTM` I was able to trim a second off the time. Though I ended up using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` which trimmed off 2 seconds.

Comment: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` seemed like it was doing what I wanted, though the physical size of the Image never changed. I did end up using `CGContextConcatCTM` Thank you

Comment: The `scale` parameter in the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` affects the pixel-to-point ratio (namely 1 for non-retina, 2 for retina), not the transform matrix for the rendering size, so of course the physical size of the image wasn't affected by this. That's why I suggested `CGContextConcatCTM(ctx,CGAffineTransformMakeScale(ratio,ratio))` and not this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [AliSoftware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803787/alisoftware), Here is the Code I ended up using:

```
    -(UIImage *) createScreenShotThumbnailWithWidth:(CGFloat)width{
        if (IoUIDebug & IoUIDebugSelectorNames) {
            NSLog(@"%@ - %@", INTERFACENAME, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) );
        }
            // Size of our View
        CGSize size = editorContentView.bounds.size;

            //Calculate the scal ratio of the image with the width supplied.
        CGFloat ratio = 0;
        if (size.width > size.height) {
            ratio = width / size.width;
        } else {
            ratio = width / size.height;
        }
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(ratio * size.width, ratio * size.height);

            //Create GraphicsContext with our new size
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

            //Create Transform to scale down the Context
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, ratio, ratio);

            //Apply the Transform to the Context
        CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),transform);

            //Render our Image into the the Scaled Graphic Context
        [editorContentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

            //Save a copy of the Image of the Graphic Context
        UIImage* screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return screenShot;

    }
```

Comment: `renderInContext:` is now the time eater. Instruments says roughly 800ms for renderSubLayers, and 800ms for foregroundLayer.